# How often does the Recovery Volume mount itself?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, high-sierra, recovery, apfs

From my understanding about the new APFS System for macOS High Sierra, the Recovery partition `disk1s3` will shortly mount and unmount itself to check for updates in the background. Ive noticed from console logs that it checks for updates about every day, depending how long my macbook is active.

My main question is what triggers the Recovery partition to mount for updates and how often does it mount(i believe its a 24-hour period)? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Didn't know this. Can you provide link for reference?

Comment: @JBis it was referenced when i had a different topic in forums here: https://bit.ly/2MTtCzu

Comment: Ok thanks. Just please edit and remove the bitly link (we try not to use shorteners here)